# How to extract specific value from XML in SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, t-sql, xpath

```
<Term xmlns:xxxlocal="xx.xx.xx.xx" href="abcde?terms=1" policyTerm="1">
   <EffectiveDate>2012-05-22T00:00:00-04:00</EffectiveDate>
   <ExpirationDate>2013-05-22T00:00:00-04:00</ExpirationDate>
   <LocationCode>XXXXXX</LocationCode>
   <ProductRef href="products/XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX" idref="XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX" version="ZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZ">
       <CachedItem name="Label" value="I NEED TO EXTRACT THIS VALUE" />
    </ProductRef>
...
```

I'm trying to extract the VALUE for the `Label1` under `<ProductRef>`.

I'm trying this but it is not working:

```
SELECT XmlDoc.value('(/Term/ProductRef[1]/CachedItem[@name=sql:variable("@Label")]/@value)[1]','varchar(100)')
```

I keep getting the error:

> *Msg 9501, Level 16, State 2, Line 1
>
>   XQuery: Unable to resolve sql:variable('@Label'). The variable must be declared as a scalar TSQL variable.*

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
SELECT @xml.value('(/Term/ProductRef[1]/CachedItem/@value)[1]','varchar(100)')
```

Demo on [**SQLFiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d41d8/8607)